# Last token doesn't get processed when using the hasNext() method

Tags: java, while-loop, merge, mergesort

I'm trying to merge two sorted files (`fn1` & `fn2`) to a 3<sup>rd</sup> sorted file (`fn3`) but am running into a problem when using a `while` loop to go through the files. Basically, when the `hasNext()` method reaches the last digit of a file, it exits the `while` loop without processing the last digit due to there not being another digit after which returns the `hasNext()` as false. Is there a way I can process the last digit while using a `while` loop? The file contents im testing with is the following but it can be any number of digits.

File 1: 5 16 47

File 2: 12 21 67

```java
int x, y;
x = fn1.nextInt();                       // read x from file F1
y = fn2.nextInt();                       // read y from file F2
while (fn1.hasNext() && fn2.hasNext()) {
    if (x <= y) {
        fn3.printf("%3d ", x);           // write x in file F
        x = fn1.nextInt();               // read x from file F1
    }                                    // end if
    else {
        fn3.printf("%3d ", y);           // write y in file F
        y = fn2.nextInt();               // read y from file F2
    }                                    // end else
}                                        // end while
```

I found this *https://coderanch.com/t/525457/java/Trouble-hasNext* and it seems like I have to declare my `x` and `y` variables inside the `while` loop but I can't do that due to the `if` statement!

Also, here is my professors' pseudo code if it's any help:

```
pseudo code 
//open input file F1, F2 
openinput(F1);   
openinput(F2);     
 
//open input file F3 
openoutput(F3);     
 
// read x from file F1 
x = readinput(F1);   
 
// read y from file F2 
y = readinput(F2);   
 
// eof stands for end of file,  
while (!eof(F1) && ! eof(F2)) 
If ( x ≤ y) { 
    // write x in file F3 
write(F3, x);    
 
// read x from file F1 
x = readinput(F1);   
}   // end if 
else{ 
    // write y in file F3 
write(F3, y);   
  
// read y from file F2 
y = readinput(F2);   
}  // end else 
// endwhile

// append F3 unprocessed data in F2 
If (eof(F1)) .........  
 
// append F3 unprocessed data in F1 
If (eof(F2)) .........  
 
Close all I/O files. 
//end pseudo code
```

Comment: shouldn't the condition be ```||```. right now you are counting on both file running out of numbers at the same time, which won't happen for example if every number in file 1 is smaller than file 2 it's going to run out of number and end the loop

Comment: I think you could make your life a lot easier if you just store them in two array list first and then merge the two list instead

Comment: @Icarus I 100% agree with you in using an array to store the values of the files. I should have pointed out that this assignment is for external sorting and we cannot use arrays since we might run out of memory if the files are really big. Also, i tried using the || condition but the problem of the last digit not processing still seems to be an issue. I've edited my question to include the pseudo code my professor gave us if that's any help.

Comment: @Abra I've edited the post to include the file contents.

Comment: So you just need to add the trailing loops to consume the rest of `fn1` or `fn2`.

Comment: @shmosel Any idea on how to do that? If you could point me in the right direction, that would be awesome!

Comment: You have all the pieces. Just adapt the logic a little.

Comment: it's in your pseudo code ```// append F3 unprocessed data in F2 
If (eof(F1)) .........  
 
// append F3 unprocessed data in F1 
If (eof(F2)) .........  ```

Comment: @Icarus But It's not the end of the file! Im using the same number of digits for both files so they should reach the end of file at the same time. My problem is that the last digit doesn't get processed because the hasNext() method doesn't see a token after the last digit so it just exits the while loop.